# Can't convert timestamp to date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to convert a timestamp saved in my table to date, but for some reason, it returns the same date, or it gives me a strange error:

`ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string`

Here is what I have tried with no success:
The type of `Change_Date` field is `TIMESTAMP(6)`

`SELECT TO_DATE (Change_Date, 'YYYY-MON-DD') FROM test` it gives me the above error.

`SELECT CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS DATE) FROM test` no change in the format.

`SELECT  TO_DATE(To_Char(Change_Date)) FROM test` no change.

`SELECT To_Char(to_date(Change_Date, 'DD-MON-YY')) FROM test` no luck.

and few other tricks that I can't remember, but it always returns the same format - `16-DEC-14 07.59.24.097000 AM`

I need to output only the date - for example `16-DEC-14`

I know that I'm missing a really small part here, but I'm not able to spot it. Can you give me a push!

Comment: What does change_date return by its self

Comment: Dates don't have formats, so casting from one date type to another doesn't change anything, unless rounding occurs. Converting a date to a string or parsing a string to a date uses formats. All the conversions in your post are unnecessary. You only need to convert the date to a string if you want to return a string instead of a date to the client for some reason

Comment: Also what do you want the output to be?

Comment: @Slim what are you really trying to do here? Are you trying to truncate the time part of the timestamp?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, Panagioti, this is exacly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Matt I want to return just the date.  `change_date` returns `16-DEC-14 07.59.24.097000 AM`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To truncate the time part of a DATE or TIMESTAMP value you should use the [TRUNC](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions235.htm#SQLRF06151) function. By default it truncates the time part, returning a date with a time of midnight.

Depending on your database version you can directly truncate the timestamp, or you may have to cast it to a DATE first, eg

```
TRUNC(Change_Date)
```

or

```
TRUNC(CAST(Change_Date as Date))
```

As I mentioned in the comment, Dates don't have formats. Date-typed values, just like numbers,  are stored in a specific binary format that isn't affected by locales or formats. Formats come into play only when you try to convert a date to a string or parse a string as a date.

Confusion arises because dates (and numbers) are sometimes [converted to strings implicitly](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF00214),eg for display purposes, when comparing values of different types. In this case the database will use a default locale to convert from one type to the other before making the comparison.

This implicit conversion causes people to think that dates and numbers have a specific format when they don't.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT To_Char(Change_Date, 'DD-MON-YY') FROM test`

**EDIT** DO A TEST

```
SELECT SYSDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                   
-------------------- -------------------------------------
16-DEC-2014 10:30:59 16-DEC-2014 10.30.59.608090000 EUROPE/AMSTERDAM                            




SELECT to_char(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY'), to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY')  FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY')
----------------------------- ---------------------------------------
16-12-2014                    16-12-2014
```

*I need to output only the date - for example 16-DEC-14*

16-DEC-14 isn't a date it's a string representation of a date

Comment: Nothing changed. It is still returning `16-DEC-14 07.59.24.097000 AM`

Comment: @Slim To be honest, I find that hard to believe. Did you run the *exact* statement provided by Robert? Or did you wrap it in an additional conversion? This statement will *never* return a time part.